# System of differential equations - find general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equations

$$\left \{\begin{matrix}\dfrac{dx}{dt} & = & x-2y, \\
\dfrac{dy}{dt} & = & 2x+5y.\end{matrix}\right .$$

So far, I was able to find the eigenvalues to be $3$ (with multiplicity $2$). Also, I think the eigenvector is $(-1,1)$.

Comment: $$x' + y' = (x + y)' = 3(x + y) \implies \dots$$ If you want to do it via linear algebra methods, you'll need to find a second eigenvector of the system.

Comment: @WillJagy I didn't say independent.

Comment: $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-2 & 0  \\ 
2 & 1  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-\frac{1}{2} & 0  \\ 
1 & 1  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
$$



$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-2 & 0  \\ 
2 & 1  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 1  \\ 
0 & 3  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
-\frac{1}{2} & 0  \\ 
1 & 1  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & -2  \\ 
2 & 5  \\  
\end{array}
\right)
$$